# Problems with php.ini

Tags: apache, xampp, php

My problem is related to the `php.ini` file I think, but it might be something else.

Let's say we have a site architecture where inside the root directory there is another directory named `img` and a file named `index.php`. Inside the directory `img` there is a file named `image.jpg`.

So in `index.php`, to refer to an image, I would use `/img/image.jpg`.

My question is, what should I change in `php.ini` to be able to write `img/image.jpg` instead of `/img/image.jpg`.

Thanks

Comment: You should change your odd coding quirk/requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths get resolved by the web browser, not by PHP. There is no way to override this behavior on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing PHP can do. You could essentially do that with Apache rewrites but it makes much more sense to just use absolute paths. You should not try to mix absolute and relative paths because it will only cause problems for you in the future. What's wrong with adding the '/' to the front of the path?

Not only that, but it will confuse the hell out of people trying to debug your code that all of your relative paths are becoming absolute paths in Apache.

Comment: Here is the thing. I just installed xampp for the first time and I noticed that my websites that work just fine online doesn't work so well local with xampp and apparently it have to do with the /.

Comment: That's because the web server uses a web root which all files are expected to be in, whereas your local machine, the '/' could mean anything. And wow, you're considering doing this just so you can test it easier on your *local* machine? Tisk tisk.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what should I change in php.ini to be able to write `img/image.jpg` instead of `/img/image.jpg`.

This is answering your question but not the answer you would like to hear. It quite simple, let's first list the ini settings:

1. [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.auto-prepend-file) (probably in conjunction  with [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path))

And that's all. How it works:

Prepend a php script with the ini directive. inside that file, you [start output](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) buffering with your own callback function:

```
function callback($buffer)
{
  // slash that image that you want to write without slash
  return (str_replace("img/image.jpg", "/img/image.jpg", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");
```

You are now able to write `img/image.jpg` instead of `/img/image.jpg` because your output filter function does re-write it for you.

But take care that you're not trying to fix the wrong end with this. General rule of hypertext references apply, see [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)
, [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)
 and [Hypertext Markup Language - 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866)
.